# Django GraphQL documentation explorer encoding

Tags: django, encoding, graphql

I have a problem with GraphQL documentation explorer. As you can see on the picture, it has problems with russian text, it shows some, I guess, twice encoded strings like "\\u041c\\u043e\\u0441". How to fix this?

[image]

ADDED:

For now I did a patch like this (see `.replace('\\\\', '\\')` part):

```
from graphql.type import introspection

def resolver(input_val, *_):
    if input_val.default_value is None:
        return None
    if isinstance(input_val.default_value, str):
        return introspection.print_ast(introspection.ast_from_value(input_val.default_value, input_val)).replace('\\\\', '\\')
    return introspection.print_ast(introspection.ast_from_value(input_val.default_value, input_val))

introspection.__InputValue = introspection.GraphQLObjectType(
    "__InputValue",
    description="Arguments provided to Fields or Directives and the input fields of an "
    "InputObject are represented as Input Values which describe their type "
    "and optionally a default value.",
    fields=lambda: introspection.OrderedDict(
        [
            ("name", introspection.GraphQLField(introspection.GraphQLNonNull(introspection.GraphQLString))),
            ("description", introspection.GraphQLField(introspection.GraphQLString)),
            ("type", introspection.GraphQLField(introspection.GraphQLNonNull(introspection.__Type))),
            (
                "defaultValue",
                introspection.GraphQLField(
                    type=introspection.GraphQLString,
                    resolver=resolver,
                ),
            ),
        ]
    ),
)
```